# Would I need to keep track of 1099s?

Tags: united-states, contractor, bookkeeping, form-1099

I run a small business and am looking to pay some people to assist with sales as contractors. They would be paid via something like paypal, google or square. Do I still need to file a 1099 for each person paid over $600? Or would I just record the amounts paid as a single deduction when the time comes?

I'm trying to determine how much book keeping I would need to do at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You have to file and issue each one of them a 1099 if you are paying them $600 or more for the year](http://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1099msc/ar02.html).

Because you need to issue a 1099 to them (so they can file their own taxes), I don't think there's a way that you could just combine all of them.

Additionally, you may want to [make sure that you are properly classifying these people as contractors](http://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Small-Businesses-&-Self-Employed/Independent-Contractor-Self-Employed-or-Employee) in case they should be employees.

Comment: Important exception: You do not need to issue a 1099 for corporations. So if any of these people are doing business as an S-corp, C-corp, or LLC, you don't need to submit a 1099 for them.

Comment: @BenMiller, great point, yes. What I wrote applied to paying individuals.